# Why printf() function broke pointer adress in C?

Tags: c++

I try an example about array reverse like that:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define arr_size(dizi) (sizeof(dizi)/sizeof((dizi)[0]))

template<class F>
int* dizi_cevir(F (&dizi)){
    int boyut = arr_size(dizi);
    int donen[boyut];

    for (int i=0, k=boyut-1;i<boyut;i++,k--){
        donen[i] = dizi[k];
    }

    return donen;
}

int main() {
    int dizi[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("cevirmeden önce dizi(before reverse):\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",dizi[0],dizi[1],dizi[2],dizi[3],dizi[4]);

    int *pt = dizi_cevir(dizi);
    printf("cevirdikden sonra(after reverse):\n"); //problem is here
    printf("%i %i %i %i %i",*(pt),*(pt+1),*(pt+2),*(pt+3),*(pt+4));
    return 0;
}
```

but i have a output something like this:

```
cevirmeden önce dizi(before reverse): 
1 2 3 4 5 
cevirdikden sonra(after reverse): 
5 4 3 2 8
        ^==== must be 1,when i delete or move above printf() which include (after reverse) then it prints 1
```

What's the reason of this situation?

Comment: `return donen;` - Your program invokes *undefined behavior*. `donen` no longer exists as soon as the function returns, yet you return, and dereference, a dangling pointer to it. Fyi, clang returns a beautiful warning about this, which should not be ignored: "main.cpp:15:12: Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'donen' returned"

Comment: Use std::vector instead of arrays. std::vector also has a reverse iterator.

Comment: @manni66 i dont want to use c++ std libraries,i just try an examle about pointer arrays

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your commend,is there any way to return pointers or int array[] in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class F>
int* dizi_cevir(F (&dizi)){
    int boyut = arr_size(dizi);
    int donen[boyut]; // <-- Stack allocated

    for (int i=0, k=boyut-1;i<boyut;i++,k--){
        donen[i] = dizi[k];
    }
    return donen; // And returned?!
}
```

Quite simple, you must never return a pointer to a variable which was allocated further up in the stack. In this case, `donen` is only guaranteed to exist for the duration of the execution of the `dizi_cevir` function.

It only works *by chance* for the first 4 elements, as `printf` did not touch them.

Once the function `dizi_cevir` returned, the memory where the local variables were stored is free to be re-purposed by any future function call.

Comment: Never return a *pointer* to a variable allocated on the stack*

Comment: @natrollus Either reverse it in-place (so you store the result in the input array), or you will need to allocate the result array on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: @natrollus or let the caller allocate the reversed array and pass it as an argulent